# Spring MVC session not cleared on server restart ( Tomcat )

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have noticed that when a I store a string in the session, and then restart the server ( not publish )
sometimes the same session variable will still be set...

Should it not clear on server restart? If not, how can I configure this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think, tomcat can store its session in work folder (in CATALINA_HOME by default), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this the default behaviour?

Comment: I think so. Try delete work folder.

Comment: There has to be a way to configure this, rather than manually delete a directory...

Answer (score 1):

Try in CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml uncomment this line.

```
<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
```

Comment: I will look into this later today :)